# Load a single react page as a standalone app

Tags: reactjs

Sorry if the title is confusing, I am unsure how to word it.

Basically I have a ReactJS Visitor Management system that people can log into using a QR code.

However, as Reactjs is an SPA, I am trying to load a page outside of the SPA framework onto the visitors phone.

I would have to load the entire app into the visitors phone to get to the page.

Is there a way to do this without having to make a vanilla html page and building an api system to pass data to the backend?

Here is the running app https://vmsnz.netlify.app/

Clients make a business on their login system. Then visitors see the login screen that is shown here https://vmsnz.netlify.app/visitorLogin

"Go to QR Page" will take you to the QR code, and if logged in to a mobile version.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.
I needed to change my react-router-dom to include basename

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(createRoutesFromElements(
   ....
  ), { basename: '/' });
```